# Как узнать к какой версии ревизии приведена моя копия svn?

Tags: svn

Как узнать к какой версии ревизии приведена моя копия svn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Если стоит Subversion, `"svn info"` в директории с локальной копией.
2. Если в windows с установленным TortoiseSVN, правой кнопкой на директории -> свойства. Закладка Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте команду [`svnversion`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html). `svn info` не может дать полноценную информацию о ревизии рабочей копии, т.к. в SVN есть такое понятие как [mixed-revision working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs) обозначающее рабочую копию содержащую элементы относящиеся к сорвешенно разным ревизиям. А ещё `svnversion` удобен для использования во всяких скриптах.